# Laravel batch jobs stuck in horizon

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-horizon

I'm having some trouble with batch jobs and Horizon, I created a simple job as proof of concept that only performs a `sleep(3)` operation.

Then using the relatively new feature of Laravel Queue Batches I created 1 thousand jobs:

```php
$jobs = [];
for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $jobs[] = new JustSleepJob();
}

Bus::batch($jobs)
    ->name('Jobs Test')
    ->dispatch();
```

For some reason Horizon is reporting that only 33% of that batch has been processed and I don't know why nor how to remove that stuck entry from horizon.
[image: stuck job in horizon screenshot]

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Further info with versions on this issue that was closed almost immediately: https://github.com/laravel/horizon/issues/1098

Answer (score 0):

I set up a brand new Laravel project using Horizon and used the same code as yours, but it worked just fine.

[image]

I think you may have an issue in your environment. Are you able to replicate that error on a diff machine? If you are willing to upload your code to a repo, I can take a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, and i fixed with implement interface

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue
```

To all job which added to the batch.

And at laravel docs
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#defining-batchable-jobs

Describe:

> To define a batchable job, you should create a **queueable job as normal**;

The "**queueable job as normal**" By default will implement interface of

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue
```

See:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#creating-jobs